# Why does my prime generator break down?

Tags: python, python-2.x

This is a prime generator I made. I should be able to generate primes upto 20000. It should generate number of primes that is provided to it as argument. However, it only does upto 11 and stops D:. Can anyone explain what is wrong here?

```
def find_primes(limit):
    prime_holder = [2, 3, 5 ,7]
    divided_pass = 0
    for i in range(11, 20000):
        for j in range(0, len(prime_holder)):
            if i%prime_holder[j] != 0:
                divided_pass += 1
        if divided_pass == len(prime_holder):
            prime_holder.append(i)
            divided_pass = 0
        if len(prime_holder)-1 == limit:
            break
    return prime_holder

my_primes = find_primes(50)
for x in my_primes:
    print x;
raw_input()
```

Comment: If you are generating all the prime numbers in that range, you should use [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: I made a script based on SoE. But this script was the first one I made. This didn't work and I couldn't figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `divided_pass` back to `0` for every new `i`.

```
def find_primes(limit):
    prime_holder = [2, 3, 5 ,7]
    for i in range(11, 20000):
        divided_pass = 0
        for j in range(0, len(prime_holder)):
            if i%prime_holder[j] != 0:
                divided_pass += 1
        if divided_pass == len(prime_holder):
            prime_holder.append(i)
        if len(prime_holder)-1 == limit:
            break
    return prime_holder

>>> print find_primes(50)
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233]
```

**P.S** - Lists are iterable in Python, so you don't need to do `for j in range(len(...))` and can just do `for j in prime_holder: if i % j != 0`. There are better implementations for finding prime numbers in a given range (you should look into those).

You can also use a `for-else` construct where the `else` part is executed if no `break` is encountered. Now your code gets reduced to.

```
def find_primes(limit):
    prime_holder = [2, 3, 5 ,7]
    for i in range(11, 20000):
        for j in prime_holder:
            if i%j == 0:
                break
        else:
            prime_holder.append(i)
        if len(prime_holder)-1 == limit:
            break
    return prime_holder
```

Comment: A perfect use for `for-else`.

Answer (score 0):

you should clear the value of **divided_pass** on every cycle:

```
def find_primes(limit):
    prime_holder = [2, 3, 5 ,7]
    divided_pass = 0
    for i in range(11, 20000):
        for j in range(0, len(prime_holder)):
            if i % prime_holder[j] != 0:
                divided_pass += 1
        if divided_pass == len(prime_holder):
            prime_holder.append(i)
        divided_pass = 0
        if len(prime_holder)-1 == limit:
            break
    return prime_holderdivided_pass
```